# =COUNTIF using exclusion?

Tags: excel, countif

The scenario is I have "B" and "W" generated randomly in column B and column C. I used "=countif(B2:B286, "W") to count how many "W"'s there are in Column B. I need to do the same in column C, but I need to make sure that I do NOT count the "W"'s in column C that have B's next to them in column "B".  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,"W") - COUNTIFS(B:B,"W",C:C,"W")
```